# how to make Android Studio or IntelliJ show error when using `==` to compare strings instead of `equals()`?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, intellij-idea

it happens some times that you compare two strings using `==` instead of `equals` and everything seems fine, but your code doesn't  act as it should be and after wasting some portion of time you get that you are using wrong way to compare strings.

this happens more to people coming from C++ or C#. and more when you are comparing a field of two same object which you don't attention to their field types when fast-coding.

since the usage of `==` to compare string references is almost a Never.**How can we make Android Studio hint about this as an error  ?**

Comment: imo: the best way to do this is -> not at all. Yes, for most it will make sure they don't compare their values the right way, but this will make it impossible to compare references, which, from time to time, is needed.

Comment: you are right but Ive been developing Android for 5 years and never used reference comparison for strings up to now. plus that you can disable this inspection in those very rare times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to achieve this you must go to:
**Settings** -> **Editor** -> **Inspection** -> **Probable Bugs** -> **String comparison using '==', instead of 'equals()'**

[image]
[image]

then in the right panel change the **severity** to the **Error**

hereafter the IDE wont let you use `==` to compare two string.

Comment: do you have a solution for eclipse as well?

Comment: i just checkout out inspection options in Eclipse and i couldn't find something like this there. the inspection options in eclipse are so limited.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer checkout Katharine answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good plugin to highlight errors like this: [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/). It is available for various IDEs including IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse.

Comment: haha yes :D "It is available for various IDEs including IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse."

Comment: I answered for intelliJ and Android Studio using internal fetures of them. your answer is great for people using Eclipse.

Comment: True :) I already upvoted your answer but just wanted to point out an alternative for other IDEs (though I'm also using sonarlint with the jetbrains ides)

Comment: yes i know and upvoted yours cause that was helpful . thanks.